# Dynamic Population of Popup Menu - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, popup, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

Another GUIDE question.

I created a GUIDE figure with a pop up menu. The elements of the menu are determined dynamically when calling the figure. Example: `myGUI(data, popupNames)` should be called and then the strings included in popupNames should be used to label the choices. I am able to do that in the callback for the popup menu. However that means that the popup will not be populated until  I actually press the on the popup menu and choose the first (curently empty) choice.

My question is how would I be able to populate it dynamically through the create function (or any other function). I also need to do the same thing with a uitable (populate the row and column names, though this one is not dynamic)

My failed attempt, which led me to realizing that I can't access the handle data in the create functions, was as follows:

```
% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function popupmenu1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.popupNames = varargin{2};
set(hObject, 'String', {handles.popupNames{1:end}});

% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function uitable1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

handles.data = varargin{1};

t = uitable(handles.uitable1);
set(t,'Data',handles.data{1})
set(t, 'ColumnName', {'a', 'b', 'c'})
set(t,'RowName', {'1', '2', '3'})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GUIDE generates a `myGui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)`. In there, you can initialize your strings:

```
function myGui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

    handles.output = hObject;

    set(handles.popupmenu1, 'String', varargin{2});

    set(handles.uitable1, 'Data', varargin{1});
    set(handles.uitable1, 'ColumnName', {'a' 'b' 'c'});
    set(handles.uitable1, 'RowName', {'1' '2' '3'});

    guidata(hObject, handles);
end
```

Note the use of [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) which updates the handle structure for the GUI with the new `handles`. If you don't call `guidata` whenever you change the `handles` structure, the changes you've made won't be reflected.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Most importantly thanks for clearly explaining what is going on!